# How to search using a data-grid

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to take the string from a text-box when the search button is pressed, then I want the row where that data grid is placed to be highlighted. I believe that this is possible. I don't know how this can be done. Please help me out.

```
string query = " SELECT * FROM suboffice where so_id like '%" + sor_id.Text + "%' ";
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            objConn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter   subofficeTableAdapter1 =new SqlDataAdapter(query,objConn);
            SqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(subofficeTableAdapter1);
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            subofficeTableAdapter1.Fill(dTable);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;
            subofficeTableAdapter1.Update(dTable);
```

where sor is a search tab when ever i put any thing in this on run time my data grid view is updated. This program in to be made in c#

Comment: [`What have you tried?`](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Try this: 

1) Google
2) Stackoverflow search
3) If neither give something, post question with code...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210781/search-in-datagridview-c-sharp-winfom
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989242/searching-a-datagridview-for-a-match-or-partial-match
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797946/search-datagridview-on-user-keypress

Comment: what type of application? winforms? wpf? asp.net?

Comment: Attention: Your code is suitable for sql-injection!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Forms, here is a start. You may have to modify the code for your purposes if you are going to implement some sort of functionality such as "Find Next", "Find Previous", "Find All", etc.

The following is assuming you have a Button named SearchButton, a Textbox named SearchTextBox, and a DataGridView named MyDataGridView. The following code would be in the click event of your Search Button.

```
    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDataGridView.ClearSelection(); //this will clear any currently selected cells
        string searchstring = SearchTextBox.Text;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in MyDataGridView.Rows)
            foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells)
            if (c.Value.ToString().Contains(searchstring))
            {
                r.Selected = true; //this will highlight the entire row
                break; //if you want to "Select All" that are found, take this line out
            }
    }
```

Comment: i tried ur code its not working. some thing about that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at the line           if (c.Value.ToString().Contains(searchstring))

Comment: which object is returning null? is it c.value or searchstring? maybe you need to check if either of those are null just before that line